# bash's read command with stdin

Tags: bash, shell, command

I want to read a one-line text and split them, so I decided to use `read` command.
When I try like this,

```
$ echo 'a b c d' | while read -a VARARR ; do echo ${VARARR[@]}; done
a b c d
```

All works fine, but It seems like `while` command is redundant, so I tried

```
$ echo 'a b c d' | read -a VARARR
```

But, this does not work.
Why?

Comment: This is also BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the answer from [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read).

It says,

> because the commands of the pipe run in subshells that cannot modify the parent shell. As a result, the variables of parent shell are not modified